# Pointer to a memory location of another process

Tags: virtual-memory

I have come across this question:

> If process A contains a pointer to a variable in process B, is it
>   possible for A to access and modify that variable?

My intuition is that, since processes A and B are different, they should not be allowed to access each other's address space since it will violate the protection.

But after some thinking, the following questions popped in my mind and want to get clarified.

(i). When we say A has a pointer to a variable V in B, does A holds the virtual address (of process B) corresponding to V or the physical address?

I believe when we talk about address in virtual memory systems, we always talk about virtual address. Please clarify.

(ii). If A contains the virtual address, since it is possible that both A and B can have the same virtual address, it is possible that A's pagetable contains a mapping for the virtual address that A holds (which is actually the virtual address of variable V in process B).
Then when A tries to access and modify that virtual address, it modifies something in its own address space (this access will be allowed since A accesses its own address).

I think the above reasoning applies when we try to access some random virtual address from a process i.e., accidentally the address that we try to access has a valid mapping.

Please throw your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of processes and memory management in the form they appear in modern OS's is that you cannot have a pointer from one process to another. Their memory is separated and one process cannot usually see the memory of another memory. To each process it looks like it has almost all the memory of the system available to it, as if there were only this one process (and the kernel, which might map stuff into the process' memory region).

The exception is shared memory: if both processes share a shared memory region and both processes have the access rights to modify the region, then yes, one process can modify the memory of the other process (but only within the bounds of that shared memory region).

IIRC, it works like this on the lowest level: the kernel manages a list of memory regions for each process. These regions might map to physical memory. If a region isn't mapped to physical memory and the process tries to access the region, the CPU signals the kernel to make it available (for example by loading its content from a swap file/partition). If two processes use shared memory, for both processes these regions would map to the same physical memory location (or swap file location). You might want to read about [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) and [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right. This is the way that virtual memory works. However, memory **can** be shared between processes.

For example, `mmap` in Linux can  be used to create a shared mapping that will allow 2 seperate processes to access the same memory. I'm not sure if this works by mapping the virtual addresses for the 2 processes to the same piece of physical memory of by the same technique that memory mapped I/O works (pages are marked "dirty", then the operating system is responsible for doing the actual I/O), but from the point of view of the programmer, it's exactly as if 2 threads were accessing that memory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everyone said: all modern OSes have mechanisms for debugging, and that requires one process (the debugger) to access the memory of another (the debuggee). In Windows for example, there are APIs `ReadProcessMemory()`/`WriteProcessMemory()`, but there's a privilege barrier to their use.

Yes, there's some abuse potential. But how would you debug otherwise?